# Would being moved from temporary to permanent based on the project owner's opinion be a beneficial thing to put on a resume?

Tags: resume

I'm a software dev who was transitioned from a temporary employee on a 12 month term to a permanent employee (4 months into the job) a few months ago (I have held the job for 7 months). With COVID-19 likely to dramatically impact our area of business, I am updating my resume and trying to build a pipeline of options.

To clarify:
- I was hired as a temporary employee with a contract lasting 12 months. This was in September. 
- The product owner liked me and wanted me as part of the project. 
- She asked her boss (the CEO of the 500 person agency) to have me hired full time. I was hired permanently in January. 
- It is now March.

Before that, I was earning my software engineering degree.

This isn't an urgent thing because I am part of a large local government (relatively secure) and thus plan to stay, but the software I work on is not yet live, so it could be cut as a cost saving measure.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a resume is to get the interview for a job.

So, I invite you to think about **why** your product owner decided to hire you permanently.  If you can state that reason in terms of a benefit to your agency, that's best.  Something like this.

> 2019 - present: Big Agency:  Software Developer
>
> I refined the definition of a product so it would serve 30% more members of the public, in collaboration with the product owner.

Obvs you should state what you actually did for the project that caught your colleague's attention.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

You should absolutely put this on there. Especially as a new programmer fresh out of college.

Put what you did first as a bullet point, or points, with the hard numbers bolded.  For the last bullet point under they job entry, put that, based on performance, you were converted to permanent 4 months into a 12 month contract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Something like:
"Invited by management to transition to a permanent contract, thanks for my performance and contributions, less than seven months into a temporary contract."

You did well, and this impressed your employer enough to make them want to commit to keeping you around. It's a simple, strong story, telling about your ability to integrate in a new team, earning the trust of your new colleagues, and impressing management enough to make them create an exception to retain your talent.